# Swing repainting

Tags: java, swing

I'm having an animation on a JComponent.  The animation is simply a BufferedImage on which ç draw something that is moving.  To make BufferedImage appear/disappear progressively, i'm calling repaint with a clip area that is smaller than the width of my JComponent.
The problem i've got, is that when swing has to repaint the component it draws the BufferedImage outside of my clipping area bounds.
How can i improve this ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to appear and disappear, I would simply not paint it on cycles where you don't want it to display, rather than messing with the clip region for that purpose.  This would be more efficient too, since otherwise, the JVM has to calculate what part of the image is in view.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly your explanation, but the image is moving from righ to left and i want it to appear progressively when it starts from the right and disappear progressively when it reaches the left side of the area where i want it to be displayed.  If i don't paint it on some cycle then it will not appear/disappear progressively right ?